# git alias with conditional check

Tags: git, bash, shell, sh

Translating this shell command:

```
$> sh -c 'if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi'
TRUE
```

To this git alias in `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    test = !sh -c 'if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi'
```

Results in:

```
$> git test
<output-omitted> Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

*PS: Don't want to map shell scripts to git aliases.*

PS2: As [@Cyrus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815676/2381750) and [@CodeWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815667/2381750) have mentioned, one additional pair of quotes is needed to protect the alias definition against multiple levels of expansion. Nice trick to avoid semicolons provided by [@choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36815649/2381750). Thanks everyone.

Comment: `;` is a comment in `.gitconfig` how you escape a comment IDK.

Comment: Thanks @andlrc. I've just got the answer from the guys below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another solution is to put it in a string:

```
[alias]
    test = "!sh -c 'if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi'"
```

This will also work.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the most dynamic answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems semicolons have special meaning in `.gitconfig`. Fortunately, you can rewrite the command without semicolons:

```
[alias]
        test = !sh -c '[ 1 -eq 2 ] && echo TRUE || echo FALSE '
```

Comment: Note that A && B || C is not if-then-else: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015

Answer (score 3):

Try to quote complete command:

```
test = "!sh -c 'if [ 1 -eq 1 ]; then echo TRUE; else echo FALSE; fi'"
```